# Почему не проводится линия?

Tags: svg

```html
<svg width='1700' height='500' style='border:1px solid black' viewBox='0 0 400 400'>
  <path d="M15,15 L185,15 Z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Svg нет свойства `border`. Вместо его используется `stroke`

```html
<svg width='1700' height='500' style='stroke:black' viewBox='0 0 400 400'>
  <path d="M15,15 L185,15 Z"/>
</svg>
```